# Caesar Cipher in C Encryption & Decryption, ASCII values too high

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am working on an encryption/decryption code for C.
Whilst I have the code encrypting and decrypting well enough there are still some errors.
I want the users input to be in between '!' (ASCII value 32) and '~' (ASCII value 126), However, when the user puts in a character such as '~' with a fairly highly offset/key-value the output is in the extended ASCII characters range. Is there any way that I can force the output to not be in the extended character range and still decrypt/encrypt properly?

I have messed around with changing the values for "cipher" but it hasn't helped too much.

Below is my code

```
    void Encryption(char* OriginalText, int offset) {
    int i = 0;
    int cipher;
    char encrypt;
    printf("Encrypted string: \n");
    while (OriginalText[i] != '\0') {
        if (OriginalText[i] == ' ') {
            encrypt = ' ';
            printf("%c", encrypt);
            i = i + 1;
        }

        cipher = ((int)OriginalText[i] + (offset % 26) % -26);
        encrypt = (char)(cipher);
        printf("%c", encrypt);

        i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The usual strategy is to only shift letters and to leave all other characters as they are. (By the way, shouldn't there be an `else` to your `if`?) You could also rotate over a wider range; shifting from `'!'` to `'~'` is what rot47 does, for example. In that case, some letters will turn into symbols and vice versa. If the range is `[min, min + n)` and if `0 ≤ offset < n`, then `new = min + (old - min + offset) % n`.

Comment: Your `cipher` does not match [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Comment: It's not your question, but the code has a buffer overflow, for example if OriginalText is `"hello "`.

Answer (score 0):

The '%' operator has higher precedence than the '+'. 
Therefore, it applies on the result of the exprssion `offset % 26` first, and then added to `OriginalText[i]`.

In order to fix this, you should add another pair of parenthesis in the assignment to cipher:

```
cipher = (((int)OriginalText[i] + (offset % 26)) % -26);
```

Moreover, when you're dealing with ASCII characters, just to walk on the safe side and prevent annoying and unwanted bugs, you should treat your I/O as unsigned char, hence:

```
unsigned char cipher;
unsigned char encrypt;
...
cipher = ((OriginalText[i] + (offset % 26)) % 26);
encrypt = cipher;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert your character to an index between zero and the size of the alphabet (exclusive), i.e. from 0 to 25 for the ABC. Only then do the modular addition / subtraction. Finally, convert back. The best way to do this is to simply perform `character - 'a'` (in case of lowercase characters of course). Do not perform modular operations on ASCII values itself.